# Why returning a pointer of enum does not work, while returning directly the array works (opposite to case of other variable arrays, like int)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, enums

Header file(same for both) :

```
#ifndef RESISTOR_COLOR_H
#define RESISTOR_COLOR_H

#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum { BLACK, BROWN, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, GREY, WHITE } resistor_band_t;

uint16_t color_code(resistor_band_t color);
resistor_band_t * colors();

#endif
```

Why returning pointer to `col` array do not work:

```
#include "resistor_color.h"
#include <stdio.h>

resistor_band_t * colors(){
  resistor_band_t col[]={BLACK, BROWN, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, GREY, WHITE};
  resistor_band_t *ptr = col; 
  return ptr;
}

uint16_t color_code(resistor_band_t color){
  return color;
```

ERROR : `test/test_resistor_color.c:36:test_colors:FAIL: Element 0 Expected 0 Was 36`

While returning just the array works(opposite to that with `int` arrays) :

```
#include "resistor_color.h"
#include <stdio.h>

resistor_band_t band[] = {BLACK, BROWN, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, GREY, WHITE};

resistor_band_t * colors(){
  return band;
}

uint16_t color_code(resistor_band_t color){
  return band[color];
}
```

here's the test suite (test_resistor_color.c :  *here only the function that checks `colors()` function)*

```
#include "vendor/unity.h"
#include "../src/resistor_color.h"

#define ARRAY_LENGTH(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))

static void test_colors(void)
{
   TEST_IGNORE();
   const resistor_band_t expected[] = {
      BLACK, BROWN, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW,
      GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, GREY, WHITE
   };
   TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected, colors(), ARRAY_LENGTH(expected));
}
```

Comment: These arrays look like ones where the values should never change. Consider adding `const` to the array definitions and the pointer types.

Comment: Sure, I will add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code below the array `col` is allocated on the stack of the function `colors`. After return from the function, the pointer is already invalid since the stack is gone.

```
resistor_band_t * colors(){
  resistor_band_t col[]={BLACK, BROWN, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, GREY, WHITE};
  resistor_band_t *ptr = col; 
  return ptr;
}
```

You can make it `static` or declare in global scope instead.